# problems with some linux partitioned sd cards on one win7 PC

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, sd-card

I have a sd card that I can use on my laptop (Asus N76VZ). if i prepare the card for using it in raspi the computers volume management crashes if it tries to read it.

On my second computer (i do not remember the model - some small acer) that is no problem. I can see all the partitions and manage them.

Both using win7

Any suggestions about that could be the reason and if it is a hardware, driver, windows problem?

On each attempt, the event view shows following Error 2 times:

```
Protokollname: System Quelle:        Microsoft-Windows-BitLocker-Driver Datum:         19.01.2018 21:35:15 Ereignis-ID:   24620 Aufgabenkategorie:Keine Ebene:         Fehler Schlüsselwörter: Benutzer:      SYSTEM Computer:      TheBigOne Beschreibung: Überprüfung des verschlüsselten Volumes: Die Volumeinformationen auf "S:" können nicht gelesen werden. Ereignis-XML: <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">   <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-BitLocker-Driver" Guid="{651DF93B-5053-4D1E-94C5-F6E6D25908D0}" />
    <EventID>24620</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-01-19T20:35:15.079396900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>229245</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="88" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>TheBigOne</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />   </System>   <EventData>
    <Data Name="ErrorCode">0xc00000a3</Data>
    <Data Name="Volume">S:</Data>
    <Data Name="WritePhase">0x0</Data>   </EventData> </Event>
```

and a few of this:

```
Protokollname: System
Quelle:        Disk
Datum:         19.01.2018 21:35:33
Ereignis-ID:   11
Aufgabenkategorie:Keine
Ebene:         Fehler
Schlüsselwörter:Klassisch
Benutzer:      Nicht zutreffend
Computer:      TheBigOne
Beschreibung:
Der Treiber hat einen Controllerfehler auf \Device\Harddisk2\DR35 gefunden.
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Disk" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49156">11</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-01-19T20:35:33.757226700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>229248</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>TheBigOne</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\Harddisk2\DR35</Data>
    <Binary>0304800001000000000000000B0004C0030100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F7C90B0400000000FFFFFFFF06000000580000000000000000200A1240022000000200003C00000000B0360F80FAFFFF6817890C80FAFFFF000000000000000010DC720980FAFFFF1060A30780FAFFFFFE1F260000000000280000261FFE00000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: On the computer that crashes, is there anything related in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @mtak thanks for that hint - i added two events that seems to occur regularly when inserting SD cards of that kind